# How to commit group transaction to a stored procedure in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, transactions, commit

I have a procedure that inserts data to a table and has a commit statement at the end. It commits each call to the procedure and inserts data.

```
create or replace procedure abc
begin 
  insert stmt;
  commit;
end;
```

Now, I wonder if there is a way I can commit multiple inserts to the table through the procedure at the end of the transaction(group transaction). Which means, i don't want to commit each time when the procedure gets called(from the front end), but after several calls to the procedure i need this to be committed.

Comment: how do you execute that procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the commit from the procedure all together. Move it to the calling process. For example:

```
Create or replace procedure procedure abc(p1 varchar2, p2 ...)
is
begin
    insert ....
end abc;
```

The calling process then becomes something like:

```
begin 
    for vars in (select c1, c2, ... from tab)
    loop
       ....
       abc(vars.v1, vars.c2, ...);
   end loop; 

   COMMIT;  -- only when transaction is complete;
end ;
```

NOTE; the calling process does NOT have to be plsql, it can be anything that can make the database connection.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create the procedure with parameter. The parameter can take the values: Y or N (or how you need) and based on that value, you will commit, or not.

Example:

```
create or replace procedure abc (commit_y_n varchar2) as
begin 
insert stmt;
if abc.commit_y_n == 'Y' then {
commit;
}
end;
```